# Options for PDF files returned by Google search

Tags: google-search

Why are there three or two options for PDF files returned by Google search: cached and/or similar, and share?

Particularly, "cached" isn't always available, but I hope to view it using "cached" since it is the quickest way to view the PDF file.

Answer (score 4):

The 3 options are not specific to PDF: all links have them (except for cache which depends on availability):

- The Cached option sends you to the cached page,
- The Similar option performs a new related search for you,
- The Share option lets you do so on Google+.

Comment: Why don't some results have caches?

Comment: http://www.googleguide.com/cached_pages.html: "The Cached link will be omitted for sites whose owners have requested that Google remove the cached version or not cache their content, as well as any sites Google hasn’t indexed."